# Apply class to Fancybox links/buttons that control 'next', 'previous', and 'close'

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the following jquery to close a div when anything without the class 'click' is clicked (for empty space and certain other divs).

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('click')) {
        $('#div').hide();
              }
});
```

I don't want opening the fancybox gallery to close the div (fancybox 2.1.5), so I've applied the 'click' class to everything related to fancybox in my html.

```
<div class="fancybox_container click">
<a class="fancybox_gal click" rel="gallery" href="1s.jpg"><img src="1l.jpg" class="click"></a>
<a class="fancybox_gal click" rel="gallery" href="2s.jpg"><img src="2l.jpg" class="click"></a>
<a class="fancybox_gal click" rel="gallery" href="3s.jpg"><img src="3l.jpg" class="click"></a>
</div>
```

I can click any of the images without hiding the div. But, when I click the "next" or "previous" or "close" links/buttons that fancybox generates over the image, the div closes.

I edited jquery.fancybox.js, adding the 'click' class to the href links for those buttons, that didn't work.

Any ideas how to apply this class to those links? Or some workaround?

Here's a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gn27e3rs/) illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[WORKING:DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gn27e3rs/3/) : **UPDATED**

**JS** : **UPDATED**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) /* it executes on mouse click anywhere on document*/
{
var container = $(".click, a, .fancyboc_gal, .fancybox_container, img"); /* all those div's or links on which if clicked should not close your behind div(#othercontent)*/

if (!container.is(e.target) /* Now Check that click you did is not on gallery  */
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    $("#othercontent").hide();
}
```

});

Comment: I added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn27e3rs/) to the OP. I honestly can't made heads or tails of your demo. Maybe you could apply it to my demo?

Comment: sorry, but still not clear about what you asking for

Comment: When one clicks the "next" or "previous" or "close" buttons in the fancybox gallery, it closes the div that I don't want to be closed. I'm trying to find a way to apply the 'click' class to those links/buttons so that they won't hide the div.

Comment: you don't want to close the #othercontent div on such clicks? if you want to hide that div then when? or not at all

Comment: I want to hide the #othercontent div when clicking empty space (which works). But I don't want any clicks of the images or fancybox image gallery to cause it to close. I want to be able to click to scroll through and close the gallery without hiding the #othercontent div.

Comment: or you don't want it at all to hide throughout

Comment: ohh.. ok wait got it, will try

Comment: Read the comments carefully in JS Code, if still you find difficult to understand, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: I'm implementing it in my project, and it does work. The trouble is: it means I have to change the structure of a lot of my existing jquery. The event.target click class thing is used in a lot of different ways. And they all have to change if I want to use this method. Is there any way to achieve the same effect within the code ecosystem I already have?

Comment: Actually its tough to say because don't know your whole scripts and code, but you can add event.stopPropagation() in function, for more https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Was it helpful the last comment

Comment: Is there a way to make it work along the lines of `if (!$(event.target).hasClass('click'))`, as in my original [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn27e3rs/), keeping that code intact, instead of the variable and container stuff you introduced?

Comment: a bit complicated, it could have been easier using the `tpl` API option